# Facebook 'Like' not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-like

I am trying to link the Facebook Like button on my page and link it with Google Analytics.
When doing console.log and ga(send()) 'hitCallBack' the results come out okay.
However, the Facebook likes don't show up in my Social Plugins tab on my Google Analytics.
Note: I am testing this on a localhost.

My script:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-159331778-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
</script>

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- Facebook Javascript SDK -->
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=2854011081354723";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    console.log("fbAsyncInit")
    FB.init({
        appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v6.0'

    });console.log("FB.init works");
    var currentPage = $(document).attr('title');
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(href,widget) {
        ga('send', {
            'hitType': 'social',
            'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
            'socialAction': 'Like',
            'socialTarget': href,
            'page': currentPage,
            'hitCallback': function() {
                alert('Callback success');
            }
            });
        console.log("FB Like Sent");
    });        
};
</script>
```

And my Facebook Like div:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="xxxxxxxxxx" data-width="" data- 
layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
```

The pageviews come through but not the facebook like info.
Help needed.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the console.log for FB Like Sent?

Comment: Yes. The console.log shows up

Answer (score 0):

I see you are implementing Google Analytics, and Facebook Analytics separately. My first advice is to implement Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager. Second, remove Google Analytics from the HTML. With JavaScript (jQuery), you can add "click listeners" which pushes an event, for example, ButtonClick (with details about the button click) to Google Tag Manager. Via Google Tag Manager, you can send the details to Google Analytics.